# Remote connection from Docker container by FTP

Tags: docker, linux, windows

I built my docker image and run it:

```
docker run --rm -P -d test:latest
```

Then I entered the command and opened connection:

```
ftp
open XXX
```

I successfully connected and entered user data. After that I try to execute:

```
ls
```

And received these messages:

```
200 Command okay.
425 Can't open data connection.
```

P.S.

I run a Linux image from Windows cmd.

Comment: Is there any firewall enabled? I’ve seen this error with FTP servers. See if this helps: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2973

Comment: you want to run FTP to connect to a r emote server from within your container?